NavigationStack crashes when poping scrolling view on iOS 16
Investigating strange navigation bug in my iOS app.
I'm using NavigationStack for push-navigation and a dedicated ObservableObject Communicator which holds current NavigationStack's path.
What I want to achieve:
Basically, I have a Root top-view and a Child subview. On button's tap Child view is pushed to the NavigationStack, and when navigationBar's Back button is pressed, Child view should be popped from stack.
The problem:
When app is running on iOS 16.3 device, I scroll a Child's content and while it is scrolling by inertia I am tapping on Back button, this actions causes a runtime crash(no crashes on iOS 17.3+). Any suggestions or workarounds to solve this issue on iOS 16 would be greatly appreciated!
I managed to extract a minimal reproducing example:
struct RootView: View {
    @StateObject var communicator = Communicator()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $communicator.path) {
            VStack {
                Button("Go to child") {
                    communicator.navigate()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ChildRoute.self) { _ in
                // Child view
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        Color.indigo.frame(height: 400)
                        Color.red.frame(height: 400)
                        Color.green.frame(height: 400)
                        Color.purple.frame(height: 400)
                        Color.orange.frame(height: 400)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Communicator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    func navigate() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.path.append(ChildRoute())
        }
    }
}

struct ChildRoute: Hashable { }

Example's crash trace:
Simultaneous accesses to 0x283d74f70, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at SwiftUI`<redacted> + 1992 (0x1d5986808).
Current access (a read) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001cb55167c <redacted> + 432
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001cb5518a4 swift_beginAccess + 84
2    SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5986040 <redacted> + 944
3    SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5af130c <redacted> + 1648
4    SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4ff6eec <redacted> + 2422364
5    AttributeGraph                     0x00000001f44954ec <redacted> + 520
6    AttributeGraph                     0x00000001f4494d9c <redacted> + 424
7    AttributeGraph                     0x00000001f44938b4 <redacted> + 844
8    SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4d86034 <redacted> + 592
9    SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5b7f908 <redacted> + 4112
10   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4db926c <redacted> + 1816
11   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4d8f088 <redacted> + 1256
12   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4ed91d4 <redacted> + 2100
13   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4d8f088 <redacted> + 4956
14   Combine                            0x00000001d9bc5d00 <redacted> + 212
15   Combine                            0x00000001d9bdd5f8 ObservableObjectPublisher.send() + 596
16   Combine                            0x00000001d9bd08bc <redacted> + 140
17   Combine                            0x00000001d9c4c3e0 <redacted> + 608
18   Combine                            0x00000001d9bbc214 static Published.subscript.setter + 24
19   NavigationOnScrollCrash            0x00000001044ea090 Communicator.path.setter + 220
20   NavigationOnScrollCrash            0x00000001044e879c key path setter for Communicator.path : Communicator + 152
21   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001cb2f2274 <redacted> + 324
22   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001cb5540fc <redacted> + 56
23   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001cb2f43cc swift_setAtReferenceWritableKeyPath + 276
24   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e68784 <redacted> + 11380
25   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5e022b4 <redacted> + 6980
26   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5ab45e4 <redacted> + 12244
27   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4f8eac4 <redacted> + 7744
28   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e5520c <redacted> + 20076
29   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e15394 <redacted> + 1768
30   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4f0bbfc <redacted> + 13212
31   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e5520c <redacted> + 20076
32   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4dd5698 <redacted> + 120
33   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e5520c <redacted> + 20076
34   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d591c6c8 <redacted> + 16172
35   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d591c6c8 <redacted> + 4952
36   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5e040a8 <redacted> + 7924
37   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5986040 <redacted> + 2044
38   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5986040 <redacted> + 8044
39   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e4c768 <redacted> + 6312
40   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d573ebac <redacted> + 868
41   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4d819e4 <redacted> + 480
42   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5986040 <redacted> + 1452
43   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5cf4a20 <redacted> + 8448
44   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d5cf4a20 <redacted> + 8628
45   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d36c3d90 <redacted> + 1564
46   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d37760dc <redacted> + 208
47   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d382a854 <redacted> + 116
48   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3d7995c <redacted> + 608
49   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d45b6768 __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__ + 36
50   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3645004 <redacted> + 636
51   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3644028 <redacted> + 436
52   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3643838 <redacted> + 196
53   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3643838 <redacted> + 472
54   QuartzCore                         0x00000001d2a54d14 <redacted> + 232
55   libdispatch.dylib                  0x0000000104981fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
56   libdispatch.dylib                  0x0000000104992354 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1196
57   libdispatch.dylib                  0x0000000104992318 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
58   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d14396b8 <redacted> + 16
59   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d141a838 <redacted> + 2036
60   CoreFoundation                     0x00000001d141fc4c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
61   GraphicsServices                   0x000000020b6152c4 GSEventRunModal + 164
62   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d39152f0 <redacted> + 888
63   UIKitCore                          0x00000001d3915178 UIApplicationMain + 340
64   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4f358cc <redacted> + 2424
65   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e970f4 <redacted> + 388
66   SwiftUI                            0x00000001d4e7fb28 <redacted> + 2820
67   NavigationOnScrollCrash            0x00000001044ec36c static NavigationOnScrollCrashApp.$main() + 40
68   NavigationOnScrollCrash            0x00000001044ec438 main + 12
69   dyld                               0x00000001efd17f80 <redacted> + 2528


I cannot reproduce on iOS 16.4.

@Sweeper, reproducable on device with iOS 16.3. Edited my question to clarify that.
